# Set minimum rep to create collective discussion

Tags: discussion, feature-request, discussions-space

We all know that Collectives are here, and since new users can create a discussion, this leads to spam on the site.

This is with recent activity on [PHP Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/php/beta/discussions)

[image]

**At least 50** will be the best fit to avoid these.